# Setting an Array From MySQL then Setting Each Value As a Variable PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get 12 variables set depending on the data pulled from my database. At the moment I have it setting them into an array and then into a variable from there. However, for some reason the 12th value from my db isn't being entered into my array and then when I attempt an echo of each variable I get miss matched dates. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Example DB

> date1 = 01/01/2018
>
> date2 = 02/01/2018
>
> date3 = 03/01/2018
>
> date4 = 04/01/2018
>
> date5 = 05/01/2018
>
> date6 = 06/01/2018
>
> date7 = 07/01/2018
>
> date8 = 08/01/2018
>
> date9 = 09/01/2018
>
> date10 = 10/01/2018
>
> date11 = 11/01/2018
>
> date12 = 12/01/2018

Example Array

```
Array
(
    [0] =>; 01/01/2018
    [1] =>; 02/01/2018
    [2] =>; 03/01/2018
    [3] =>; 04/01/2018
    [4] =>; 05/01/2018
    [5] =>; 06/01/2018
    [6] =>; 07/01/2018
    [8] =>; 08/01/2018
    [9] =>; 09/01/2018
    [9] =>; 10/01/2018
    [10] =>; 11/01/2018
    [11] =>; 12/01/2018  //-----This isn't being added-----
)
```

Example Echo

> $var1 = 01/01/2018 //-----Should be 01/01/2018-----
>
> $var2 = 02/01/2018 //-----Should be 02/01/2018-----
>
> $var3 = 01/01/2018 //-----Should be 03/01/2018-----
>
> $var4 = 02/01/2018 //-----Should be 04/01/2018-----
>
> $var5 = 03/01/2018 //-----Should be 05/01/2018-----
>
> $var6 = 01/01/2018 //-----Should be 06/01/2018-----
>
> $var7 = 02/01/2018 //-----Should be 07/01/2018-----
>
> $var8 = 03/01/2018 //-----Should be 08/01/2018-----
>
> $var9 = 04/01/2018 //-----Should be 09/01/2018-----
>
> $var10 = 01/01/2018 //-----Should be 10/01/2018-----
>
> $var11 = 02/01/2018 //-----Should be 11/01/2018-----
>
> $var12 = 03/01/2018 //-----Should be 12/01/2018-----

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM system WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `status` = 'Not Set'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $arrayResults = array();
            $i = 0;

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                array_push($arrayResults, $row['date']);

                foreach($arrayResults as $value){

                    ${'var'.$i} = $value;
                    $i++;

                }

            }
            print_r($arrayResults);

            echo '<br><br>';

            echo $var1.'<br>';

            echo $var2.'<br>';

            echo $var3.'<br>';

            echo $var4.'<br>';

            echo $var5.'<br>';

            echo $var6.'<br>';

            echo $var7.'<br>';

            echo $var8.'<br>';

            echo $var9.'<br>';

            echo $var10.'<br>';

            echo $var11.'<br>';

            echo $var12.'<br>';

        }
    }
?>
```

**UPDATE**

The echo dates are now echoing in the correct order only issue now is it's still missing the first entry from the database so it's only creating 11 variables not 12. The array data prints all dates but the first, so the array entries are from [0] to [10] when it needs to be [0] to [11].

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM system WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `status` = 'No Set'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            $arrayResults = array();
            $i = 0;

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                array_push($arrayResults, $row['date']);
                ${'var'.$i} = $row['date'];
                $i++;

            }
            print_r($arrayResults);

            echo '<br><br>';

            echo $var0.'<br>';

            echo $var1.'<br>';

            echo $var2.'<br>';

            echo $var3.'<br>';

            echo $var4.'<br>';

            echo $var5.'<br>';

            echo $var6.'<br>';

            echo $var7.'<br>';

            echo $var8.'<br>';

            echo $var9.'<br>';

            echo $var10.'<br>';

            echo $var11.'<br>';


        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hey just a friendly warning that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Check out [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the "foreach" outside of the "while"

```
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            array_push($arrayResults, $row['date']);

       }

       foreach($arrayResults as $value){

                ${'var'.$i} = $value;
                $i++;

       }
```

Please note that this make loop twice over the results. You could instantiate the "$varx" directly inside the while. And if you have no other use for $arrayResults you can skip it.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        array_push($arrayResults, $row['date']);//this line is not compulsory. Depends if you need $arrayResults later.
        ${'var'.$i} = $row['date'];
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping here, I have found a small issue with this answer. When I implemented it I found that it skipped over the first two entries from my database. Any idea why this might be, as this is the closest I've gotten to an answer?

Comment: Ah yess, I did not see that. You should not make "$row = $result->fetch_assoc();" outside of the if.  The first one in your code. That explains one entry missing. Now for the second one I do not know. But try to delete this line and let me know.

Comment: And also of course as said in the answer of delboy1978uk, set $i to 1, if  you want your first variable to be $var1

Comment: I've added an update to my post providing the new code that I'm attempting to use so you can see what's going on. As I moved the `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` inside the `if` tag and still not getting the first tag. But everything is now in the correct order in the variables but still missing the 12th entry.

Comment: Resolved the problem! Removed the `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` and sure enough everything ran perfectly. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You echo from `$var1`, but your loop starts from `$i = 0`;

Try setting `$i = 1`, or start echoing `$var0` and ending on `$var11`

Comment: Thanks for that observation, very valid point. I've used the `$var0` to `$var11`  however, this hasn't resolved any of the issues. I'm still not getting the 12th date from the database to the array which would be number `[11]` in the array it only goes to the 11th number `[10]`. Also I'm still not getting my variables set correctly as they are still echoing the incorrect dates for each variable like the example displays.